# Mail subject not decoded if starts with =?UTF-8?B? javamail 1.5.6

Tags: jakarta-mail, decoding

I have a mail with following header subject

Subject: =?UTF-8?B?UmlmLiBQcmF0LjogNDhBVi04MDc5IEF0dHJhdmVyc2FtZW50byB0ZWxlZm9uaWNvIHN1cGVyaW9yZSwgaW4gY2F2ZWRpbyBlc2lzdGVudGUsIGNvbiBjYXZpIGEgRi5PLiBhbCBrbSA2NCs0MjAgZGVsbGEgbGluZWEgZmVycm92aWFyaWEgQVYvQUMgVG9yaW5vIC0gTWlsYW5vIG5lbCBDb211bmUgZGkgR3JlZ2dpbyAgW1JGSS1EUFItRFRQX1RPLklOR1xQRUNcUFwyMDE5XDAwMDUyNDRd=?=

I'm using javamail 1.5.6 to parse it and parsing that header an exception is thrown which results in a not parsed subject:

*MimeUtility class decodeWord method row 928*

com.sun.mail.util.DecodingException: BASE64Decoder: Error in encoded stream: needed at least 2 valid base64 characters, but only got 0 before padding character (=), the 10 most recent characters were: "wMDUyNDRd="

It seems a bug in javamail decoder, anyway if I open that mail with Outlook the subject is read well

For example this works fine:

```
String rawvalue = "UmlmLiBQcmF0LjogNDhBVi04MDc5IEF0dHJhdmVyc2FtZW50byB0ZWxlZm9uaWNvIHN1cGVyaW9yZSwgaW4gY2F2ZWRpbyBlc2lzdGVudGUsIGNvbiBjYXZpIGEgRi5PLiBhbCBrbSA2NCs0MjAgZGVsbGEgbGluZWEgZmVycm92aWFyaWEgQVYvQUMgVG9yaW5vIC0gTWlsYW5vIG5lbCBDb211bmUgZGkgR3JlZ2dpbyAgW1JGSS1EUFItRFRQX1RPLklOR1xQRUNcUFwyMDE5XDAwMDUyNDRd=?=";

// Get bytes from string 
byte[] byteArray = Base64.decodeBase64(rawvalue.getBytes());

// Print the decoded string  
String decodedString = new String(byteArray); 
System.out.println(rawvalue + " = " + decodedString);
```

Thx

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution, that mail subject results not valid, at least for https://base64.guru/tools/validator.

Then, debugging Javamail I've found it makes use of com.sun.mail.util.BASE64DecoderStream which uses system property *mail.mime.base64.ignoreerrors*.
Then I tried setting it to **true** and this fixed my issue.

Comment: At which point this is invalid? UmlmLiBQcmF0LjogNDhBVi04MDc5IEF0dHJhdmVyc2FtZW50byB0ZWxlZm9uaWNvIHN1cGVyaW9yZSwgaW4gY2F2ZWRpbyBlc2lzdGVudGUsIGNvbiBjYXZpIGEgRi5PLiBhbCBrbSA2NCs0MjAgZGVsbGEgbGluZWEgZmVycm92aWFyaWEgQVYvQUMgVG9yaW5vIC0gTWlsYW5vIG5lbCBDb211bmUgZGkgR3JlZ2dpbyAgW1JGSS1EUFItRFRQX1RPLklOR1xQRUNcUFwyMDE5XDAwMDUyNDRd is a valid Base64. The string you have put in your variable (containing =?= at the end) is the problem...

Comment: Yes it is... that string was the subject of a mail as you can easily understand reading my question

Comment: But the original string is not invalid. The option mail.mime.base64.ignoreerrors should not be the solution for this "problem".